# web3.eth.getAccounts() returns empty array

Tags: web3js, dapps, dapp-development, ganache

I'm trying to get accounts like that:

```
window.web3.eth.getAccounts( (error, accounts) => { console.log(accounts, error) } );
```

but it keeps returning an empty array. I'm running Ganache and I can see the accounts on MetaMask, but I cannot access them from my frontend Web3 Angular app. This used to work and now doesn't. I didn't change anything. And idea on how to fix this?

Also `web3.eth.accounts` returns an error `Error: Invalid JSON RPC response:`

This is how I init my web3:

```
if (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
      this.web3Provider = window.web3.currentProvider;
    } else {
      this.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
    }

    window.web3 = new Web3(this.web3Provider);
```

Comment: Do you have metamask connected to the local node ?

Comment: have you tried chang the port is 8545? ganache runs on this by default