# Why web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log) return empty array?

Tags: web3js, react

It's really weird that I got empty array after I tried to `web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log);`and I also got a warning which is `./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/src/scrypt.js Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`.
In this project I first cmd `create-react-app lottery_react` and then all I changed in my `lottery_react` folder are modifying App.js and creating web3.js file. I can't find what's wrong in these file. Please help!

I've seen [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/72862/web3-eth-getaccounts-returns-empty-array) but I didn't get the error that he/she gets. I only get a warning.

This is my App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import web3 from './web3';

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my web3.js file

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);

export default web3;
```

Comment: Well what node are you connected to? What is the configuration of that node?

Comment: @goodvibration Thanks for replying me. I'm using Rinkeby as my test networks. How can I see the configuration of my node? Please be more specific.

Comment: `web3.eth.getAccounts()` gives you a list of unlocked accounts on your node. It works well with Ganache (which by default sets up a node with 10 unlocked accounts). But why should it work on a public network like Rinkeby?

Comment: @goodvibration If you are using provider from browser wallet you should get the selected account as return value. That is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my MetaMask, I go to the `setting` and choose `Connection` and add site localhost. In the end, the return value from `web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log);` no longer return empty array. However, it still pops up warning `webpackHotDevClient.js:120 ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/src/scrypt.js Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`, I still can't fix it.

Answer (score 5):

Later versions of **metamask** request permission to return the account, so after requesting the accounts **metamask** extension will popup to ask you for permission in the browser.
Another thing I notice that you are using `getAccounts()`, but in later versions of **metamask** you can use `requestAccount()` instead.

**The shortest way to solve this:**

***instead of:***
 `web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log);`

***Use:***
`web3.eth.requestAccounts().then(console.log);`

After that **metamask** extention will ask you to confirm permissions then everything should go as expected :D

After confirming access permission with **metamask**, then go to **metamask** extension setting click on Connected sites, you can find your development domain.

If you find your development domain then everything is ok, and `getAccounts()` can work now, although you can keep `requestAccounts()` and everything still the same.

Comment: this is the way

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue on an old project which was working fine till recent past. Metamask changes are the cause. You have to call the enable function to access the accounts now. The privacy option in the settings have been removed. The DApp has to initiate from its side. Add this piece of code in the console. You will be prompted for a permission. Accept and then try accessing the accounts. If it works add in the code (for you in the web3.js file above `web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);`).

`window.ethereum.enable();`

For me the following is the behaviour in console for any website other than new tab:

```js
//the injected web3 is 0.20.7
web3.eth.accounts;
//returns empty array

window.ethereum.enable();
//Page refreshes after you Accept

web3.eth.accounts;
//returns the first account
```

EDIT: This also works:

`const web3 = new Web3(window['ethereum'] || window.web3.currentProvider);`

This is from Metamask API reference [page](https://metamask.github.io/metamask-docs/API_Reference/Ethereum_Provider#ethereum.on(eventname%2C-callback).

The page explains that `window.web3.currentProvider` is now legacy.

Answer (score 0):

I can connect with my private ethereum network using the following code:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accountList) {
        if(!err)
           console.log(accountList);
});
```

Hope you can do so.

Comment: This will still return empty array! I've tried.

Comment: Do you have keystores in the node which you are connecting to ? Is the node connected with web3?

Comment: Where can I connect  ```keystores```? How do I know if the node is connected with web3? All I do right now is to access into metamask accounts and then create my web provider with the web provider that metamask provided.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: Have you added accounts in metamask?

Comment: Yes, I've already added accounts in metamask.

Comment: web3.isConnected(), what is returned in this api call, please check